# Between loading my Mainpage and Splash Screen, there is white screen occurring on Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that has splash screen for ios and android. It works on ios perfectly. But I have a problem on android. The problem is: splash screen launches, after that between loading my Mainpage and splash screen, there is white screen occurring.

[I did a sample project for this problem.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/116F1WtQD0HXFcrdez-m9rcqpGP9dpyaV/view?usp=sharing)

I did this steps for splash screen:

I added splash_screen.xml to Android drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
      <padding android:left="25dp"
               android:right="25dp"
               android:top="0dp"
               android:bottom="0dp" />
      <!-- Android -> Resources-> values -> colors.xml içerisinde tanımlı bu renk -->
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@mipmap/icon"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I added splashscreen style to styles.xml

```
<style name="splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
```

I set MainLauncher value as false on MainActivity.

```
[Activity(Label = "SplahScreenSample", 
        Icon = "@mipmap/icon",
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance,
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
        MainLauncher = false,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
  //...
}
```

I added SplashActivity to Android project: (It's main launcher value is true)

```
[Activity(Label = "SplahScreenSample", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/splashscreen", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }
    }
```

Where is my problem?
Thank you in advance.

**NOTE:**
Actually I understand problem. Problem is: MainTheme has not splash screen but MainActivity Theme is MainTheme. But I don't know how can I fix this.
I tried to add splash screen to MainTheme or I tried to set MainActivity Theme is splashscreen. But these didn't work.

Comment: I could not access the sample because of without permission . You could post the full code in this thread .

Comment: I am sorry. I updated sample. You can download now. And I also will update my post. But maybe sample may be useful. Thank you for reply.

Comment: Add the line <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item> in style.cs

Comment: I tried this. But it doesn't work. But I saw this: [LearnEverything's comment.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19362/xamarin-forms-splashscreen-in-android) It works. But when I set splash screen to MainTheme, MainPage background also change

Comment: How can I set only splash screen, without changing Page's background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach works in this link: https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/

So I set MainActivity Theme as splashscreen (Theme = "@style/splashscreen"). And I changed theme in MainActivity OnCreate method in this way:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
    // Name of the MainActivity theme you had there before.
    // Or you can use global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLight
    base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    ...
 }
```

This worked.